# std::list and find(), if item/value is not found using find in list error appears

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, find

I am testing std::list with a find() function from . Before I implement it into my program, I want to see if they will work just as I think they do. At first it worked well: 
`

```
list<int> l;

l.push_back(1);
l.push_back(2);
l.push_back(9);

list<int>::iterator it = find(l.begin(), l.end(), 9);
if (*it == 9)
{
    cout << "Found";
}
else 
{
    cout << "Not Found";
}
```

In this example, output was "Found", that is right, but when I do it like this:

```
list<int> l;
l.push_back(1);
l.push_back(2);
l.push_back(9);

list<int>::iterator it = find(l.begin(), l.end(), 3);

if (*it == 9)
{
    cout << "Found";
}
else 
{
    cout << "Not Found";
}
```

It doesn't output anything, but it should output "Not Found", i get a "Debug Assertion Failed!" error, it says that "Expression: list iterator not dereferencable", how i can fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::find` returns the `end()` iterator when something is not found in a container. And de-rererencing the `end()` iterator as you do here:

```
if (*it == 9)
```

is *undefined behaviour*. To see if you found an element, check against the end iterator:

```
if (it != l.end())
{
   cout << "found\n";
}
```

Comment: so what should i do, to make it work and not de-reference the end() iterator?

Comment: @Hbo-ot I added an example.